# Error when TChart is docked

Tags: delphi, c++builder, access-violation, teechart, docking

I get an AV when I dock a Form, wich contains a `TChart`, into another Form. The error does not occure when the `AutoPaint` property of the TChart is set to `True`.

I have tested this with C++Builder XE6, XE7 and Delphi Builder XE6 with the standard version of `TeeChart`.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new application with two Forms (Form1 and Form2). Both Forms should be shown.
- In the constructor of Form1 set `DockSite = true`
- Paste the following code in the constructor of Form2:

  ```
  DragMode = dmAutomatic;
  DragKind = dkDock;
  TChart* Chart1 = new TChart(this); //don't forget to delete
  Chart1->Parent = this;
  Chart1->AutoRepaint = false;
  ```
- Start the application and dock Form2 to Form1 by dragging it with the mouse.

Can anybody reproduce this or has an idea whats going wrong?

Comment: I can reproduce it. The exception is happening in `VCLTee.TeCanvas.pas`, which of course is not included in the standard version of TeeChart. Unless someone with TeeChart Pro installed can debug it for you, you'll need to file a bug report with Embarcadero. Have you checked the TeeChart user forums at to see if this has already been reported there? (Not setting `AutoRepaint := False` makes the problem go away, as you say.)

Comment: In Delphi 2010 work fine.

Comment: Spent a couple of hours installing latest pro version and could reproduce this in XE8 as well. Unfortunately the debug with source is hopelessly broken with unit name clashes all over.

Comment: I have posted this issue at the new QC:

https://quality.embarcadero.com/i#browse/RSP-11239

Comment: I'm not sure about how do you exactly dock Form2 to Form1; nor what do you set at designtime and what at runtime. Could you please arrange an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I tried to simplify the steps to reproduce.

Comment: @Yeray, the AV happens when form2 is dropped on top of form1.

Comment: @DavidBerneda discussed with Kerem at Emb Quality Central. I guess this is answered.

Comment: Question ist answered for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like David said, the question is answered for now. I think any new updates on this issue will be seen at QC.

https://quality.embarcadero.com/i#browse/RSP-11239